# A consistent estimator with infinite expectation?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

Typical (or common) approaches to prove an estimator is consistent require finite mean and variance. The proofs usually follow from concentration bounds, e.g. Markov, Chebyshev, etc.

I'm wondering how one shows consistency of an estimator if the expectation is infinite?

Or alternately-and leading to a similar conclusion but perhaps more general-are there concentration of measure bounds when the mean is infinite? (please provide example, proof and/or links)

Comment: "the expectation is infinite" Whose expectation? the expectation of estimate?

Comment: @user158565 fair point. I suppose you could concoct examples w/an r.v. with infinite expectation but define a function/estimator of that random variable whose expectation is finite. I'd say both, i.e. infinite expectation of the random variable or infinite expectation of the estimator, although I'd think the latter case is less interesting b/c if the expectation of estimator is infinite, then so is the variance.

Comment: I think your question is meaningless. Suppose using $T(X)$ to estimate $\theta$. Then one of $E(T(X))$ and $\theta$ being infinite would result in the inconsistent of the estimate $T(X)$.

Comment: @user158565 that is why I said in the comment above, "although I'd think the latter case is less interesting b/c if the expectation of estimator is infinite, then so is the variance." Although I'm not sure how you conclude that $\theta$ is infinite, I did say that it was and you should assume that $\theta$ is finite.

Comment: Then under conditions that $\theta < \infty$ and $E(T(X)) = \infty$, then $T(x)$ cannot be the consistent estimator of $\theta$,

Comment: @user158565 that is why I said in the comment I think this latter case is not interesting. However, in the former case of my comment, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(X) = \infty$ yet the solution of the estimator is finite, $\mathbb{E}(T(X)) <\infty$ but in this case the distribution of $T(X)$ is not known, nor easily solved for because $T(X)$ is the solution to an optimization routine. In this scenario how to prove consistency? Does it make sense? If so I will edit the question to be more specific and to clarify the question.

Comment: Yes, it make sense.